# How to set user as authenticated with simple username password check in Asp .NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core

For a simple log reading application, I need to allow a form authentication based on user/password match. The check is done against data stored inside the app settings file so I don't have a DB connected that stores the user data.

Googling around I've seen I should inject the `private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;` then use the ```   await _signInManager.SignInAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = "xxx" }, false);````

But I'm not able to configure the service's dependencies...

did anyone get an example?

Thanks

#update #1

```
 public class LoginViewModel
  {
    #region Properties  

    /// <summary>  
    /// Gets or sets to username address.  
    /// </summary>  
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    /// <summary>  
    /// Gets or sets to password address.  
    /// </summary>  
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    #endregion
  }
```

Comment: Can you get the model of  the data in app settings file ?

Comment: here it's the LoginViewModel

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should use `SignInManager` when using ASP.NET Core Identity.

In your case a authentication based on Claims would be much easier. This can be achived like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string? returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        // Validate your username and password here

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            /* Set your claims here */
        };

        
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = Input.RememberMe,
            RedirectUri = returnUrl
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);


        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Within your startup process you'll need to configure it to use cookie based authentication.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>{});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

> allow a form authentication based on user/password match. The check is
> done against data stored inside the app settings file

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

1. UserModel :

   ```
   public class UserModel
   {     
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }       
   }
   ```

LoginModel:

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool RememberLogin { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

2.data in appsettings:

```
"UserModels": [
      {
        "UserName": "aa",
        "Password": "123"   
      },
      {
        "UserName": "bb",
        "Password": "123"
      }
    ]
```

3.AccountController:

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //Sample Users Data, it can be fetched with the use of any ORM
        public List<UserModel> users = null;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public AccountController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;          
            users = _config.GetSection("UserModels").Get<List<UserModel>>();           
        }


        public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "/")
        {
            LoginModel objLoginModel = new LoginModel();
            objLoginModel.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel objLoginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = users.Where(x => x.Username == objLoginModel.UserName && x.Password == objLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //Add logic here to display some message to user
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Credential";
                    return View(objLoginModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    //A claim is a statement about a subject by an issuer and
                    //represent attributes of the subject that are useful in the context of authentication and authorization operations.
                    var claims = new List<Claim>() {                    
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Username)                    
                    };
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsIdentity with the claims and authentication scheme
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsPrincipal with ClaimsIdentity
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    //SignInAsync is a Extension method for Sign in a principal for the specified scheme.
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = objLoginModel.RememberLogin });    
                    return LocalRedirect(objLoginModel.ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut() {
            //SignOutAsync is Extension method for SignOut
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            //Redirect to home page
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
```

4.In Program.cs, add below code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(x=>x.LoginPath="/account/login");
...
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

5.Login view:

```
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
            {
                <span class="text-danger">
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </span>
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="RememberLogin" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RememberLogin)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]